# Phusion Passenger - Sticky session - How to add options to set-cookie header?

Tags: nginx, passenger

Enabling sticky sessions in Phusion Passenger adds `set-cooke` header in next form:

```
Set-Cookie: _passenger_route=598708409; Path=/
```

**Questions:**

1. How to alter `Path`?
2. How to set `httpOnly` option?
3. How to set `secure` option?
4. How to set other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [relevant code](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/da395417596764e5543b97c48e13045128f613e2/src/agent/Core/Controller/ForwardResponse.cpp#L714) that sets the cookie.

1. `Path` is controlled by the baseURI
2. `httpOnly` is not set [for this reason](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/da395417596764e5543b97c48e13045128f613e2/src/agent/Core/Controller/ForwardResponse.cpp#L720):

   `// Note that we do NOT set HttpOnly. If we set that flag then Chrome
   // doesn't send cookies over WebSocket handshakes. Confirmed on Chrome 25.`
3. & 4. The current code offers no way to inject other values.

Comment: Any chance this will be changed and going to be configurable in near future?

Answer (score 1):

Path is set to the value of [`passenger_base_uri`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_base_uri)
`httpOnly` is not set by Passenger because it stops cookies being sent over websockets on Chrome (Last confirmed on Chrome 25).

To set `httpOnly`, `secure`, and other options, perhaps using something like `header_filter_by_lua_block` from the `ngx_http_lua_module` might be of use (this is included in the apt packaged nginx provided by Phusion, and can be installed as a [dynamic module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#building-as-a-dynamic-module) otherwise).

Comment: Using lua, it's kind of hacking through current behavior.
Currently I'm hacking it on the proxy level, using HAProxy, which is the same from my point of view. I'm looking to accomplish this right in Phusion Passenger, any chance this will be changed and going to be configurable in near future? Should I dig into the code for PR?

Comment: You could certainly open a feature request and/or a PR, I'm pretty sure you're not the only person who would appreciate some more flexibility in this option.

Comment: starting point hint is welcome, PP isn't a small project, thank you.

Comment: Like @OnixSO said the relevant code is here: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/da395417596764e5543b97c48e13045128f613e2/src/agent/Core/Controller/ForwardResponse.cpp#L714, and then the code for adding options is distributed through many files, but a couple options were added in 79703da3 so that should have a good list of files to check.